# Including the <title> of a HTML page from which a <form> was submitted

Tags: php, html

I have a simple email form on several html pages of this form:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

And the php something like this:

```
<?php
$message=$POST_('name');
$email_to='my@email.com';
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

I would like the `$email_subject` to contain the html page `<title>` of the page the form was submitted on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not have a hidden value on each page that gives the name or id of the page? Something like script name even: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, its `$_POST`.

If you use PHP to set the title, you can just put

`<input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo $TITLE_VAR ?>">`

in your form.